# Alternative way to using nested ifs

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for tag in tags:
    Ulist1.append(tag.get('href', None))

if len(Ulist1) > 2:
    print Ulist1[2]
    html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist1[2]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags = soup('a')
    Ulist2 = list ()

    for tag in tags:
        Ulist2.append(tag.get('href', None))

    if len(Ulist2) > 2:
        print Ulist2[2]
        html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist2[2]).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        tags = soup('a')
        Ulist3 = list ()

        for tag in tags:
            Ulist3.append(tag.get('href', None))

        if len(Ulist3) > 2:
            print Ulist3[2]
            html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist3[2]).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            tags = soup('a')
            Ulist4 = list ()

            for tag in tags:
                Ulist4.append(tag.get('href', None))
```

this is using beautiful soup to parse HTML and find the link at position 3 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 4 times. Is there a more efficient way of doing this instead of using nested loops?

Comment: If you have **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]

Comment: If you copy and paste code, and then make slight changes, you should probably factor it into a function, and pass in the differences as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You could factor it out into a function as Peter Wood said. Here's one possible implementation which shows the basic concept.

```
def print_third_recursive(tags, iterations):
    Ulist = [tag.get('href', None) for tag in tags] # more pythonic
    if len(Ulist) > 2 && iterations :
        print Ulist[2]
        html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist[2]).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        new_tags = soup('a')
        use_third(new_tags, iterations - 1)

use_third_recursive(tags, 3)
```

This could definitely be done without using recursion as well if you want the function to be simpler.

```
def print_third(tags):
    Ulist = [tag.get('href', None) for tag in tags] # more pythonic
    new_tags = []
    if len(Ulist) > 2:
        print Ulist[2]
        html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist[2]).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        new_tags = soup('a')
    return new_tags

print_third(
    print_third(
        print_third(tags)
    )
)
```

Neither implementation should have any issues if there are not 3 items in one of the tag lists as they'll just return right back out of the layers.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter and Anthony said, you can extract method and make things simpler.

But, a thumb rule in general, instead of nested ifs, you can change the condition to its complement and return.

in your example:

`if len(Ulist1) > 2:
    do_stuff()
    if len(Ulist1) > 2:
        do_more_stuff()`

instead you can write it as follows:

`if len(Ulist1) < 2:  # the compement of the original condition
    return 
do_stuff()
if len(Ulist1) < 2:  # the compement of the original condition
    return
do_more_stuff()`

So, your code can be written as follows:

```
if len(Ulist1) < 2:
    return

print Ulist1[2]
html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist1[2]).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')
Ulist2 = list ()

for tag in tags:
    Ulist2.append(tag.get('href', None))

if len(Ulist2) < 2:
    return

print Ulist2[2]
html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist2[2]).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')
Ulist3 = list ()

for tag in tags:
    Ulist3.append(tag.get('href', None))

if len(Ulist3) < 2:
    return

print Ulist3[2]
html = urllib.urlopen(Ulist3[2]).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')
Ulist4 = list ()

for tag in tags:
    Ulist4.append(tag.get('href', None))
```

And, of course, I suggest you extract the method as Anthony wrote above.

Hope it helps.